# Extract row values where NaN is present in R

Tags: r, if-statement, nan

This may be a very easy question but I already have been dealing with it for some time.

I have a data frame where column X have some "NaN" values. I need to extract the row values of columns A and B when X is "NaN" and put these in a new data frame.

I think the solution should be something similar to this if-statement but it doesn't work:

```
X = df$X
A = df$A 
B = df$B 

NaNvalues <- if (is.nan(X)) {
  data.frame(A, B)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
new_df <- df[is.nan(df$X), c("A","B")]
```

should give you what you are looking for. Here, you use the vector of indices where the column `X` is `NaN` (generated by `is.nan(df$X`) to index the rows in your data frame.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the which function:

```
nans <- which(is.na(X))
```

You also probably want to make sure you're using NaN/NA appropriately. `is.na` and `is.nan` are a little bit different. [This post cleared it up for me](https://www.r-bloggers.com/difference-between-na-and-nan-in-r/).